# Entity Framework Query Filter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Is it possible to add a sort-of a global filter to an Entity Framework object context? Such as having an ObjectMaterialized which can return an indicator of whether or not to include a given object in the result set.

Comment: Can you post example of what and how exactly you want to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. Entity framework and its built in providers don't have any support for global filters.

You can achieve some basic filtering with simple wrapper:

```
public class MyContext : ObjectContext
{
    private ObjectSet<MyEntity> myEntities;

    public Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> GlobalMyEntityFilter { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<MyEntity> MyEntities
    {
        get
        {
            if (GlobalMyEntityFilter != null)
            {
                return myEntities.Where(GlobalMyEntityFilter);
            }

            return myEntities;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: So the combination of EF and RIA Services has nothing resembling the QueryInterceptors in WCF Data Services?

Comment: I'm not sure about RIA services but EF itself doesn't have any such functionality. QueryInterceptors are specific to WCF Data Services.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like only show the active Customers? If so, you can use Inheritance and create an ActiveCustomer type and add a condition in your mapping to `Status == "Active".` Then set your Customer type as an Abstract Base Class to prevent direct instantiation. You can then query your model for `Customers.OfType<ActiveCustomer>().`